# Socket.io emitting from reciever's browser but does not emit on the sender's browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Hi I'm kinda new to socket.io so not really sure if what I'm doing is the proper/standard way but since its running fine I guess its fine. This app is chat application the script I worked on is able to store messages on database and loads them to the receiver and sender's browser... The problem is IT DOES NOT load on the sender's page unless I refresh the page whats more I find it weird because the receiver receives the data just fine without refreshing the page so I was like "what gives?"

here is the server.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
  app = require('express')(),
  http = require('http').Server(app),
  io = require('socket.io')(http);

var validator;
var messages = [];

var sequelize = new Sequelize('schat', 'root', '');

app.use('/assets', require('express').static(__dirname + '/assets'));
app.use('/temp', require('express').static(__dirname + '/temp'));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send(validator);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  // Send all previously sent messages
  for( i in messages ) {
    socket.emit('chat message', messages[i]);
  }

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);

    // Push the message into the in-memory array.
    messages.push(msg);

    // Storage the message for when the application is restarted.
    sequelize.query('INSERT INTO chat_storage(chat) VALUES("'+msg+'")').success(function() {
      // Insert was successful.
    }).error(function (err) {
      // Error inserting message
    });

    // Send the message to everyone
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

function getStdout(command, args, fn) {
  var childProcess = require('child_process').spawn(command, args);
  var output = '';
  childProcess.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
  childProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    output += data;
  });
  childProcess.on('close', function() {
    fn(output);
  });
}

// Load Messages
sequelize.query('SELECT chat FROM chat_storage ').success(function (rows)  {
  for( i in rows ) {
    messages.push(rows[i].chat);

  }
  getStdout('php', ['message.php'], function(output) {
    validator = output;
    http.listen(3000, function(){
      // Start server.
    });
  });
}).error(function (err) {
  // Error!
});
```

Then this is the page that loads the chat

```
<?php startblock('script') ?>

 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>

 var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li class="bubble">').text(msg));
  });


    </script>


  <?php endblock(); ?>
```

Any suggestion or am I missing something?? I tried changing `socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', msg);` to `socket.emit('chat message', msg);` but it does not work it does do load on the sender's browser but not on the reciever please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:)

Either add the message locally in the client with this line:

```
$('#messages').append($('li').text($('#m').val()));
```

Or replace the following:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', msg);
```

With this:

```
io.sockets.emit('chat message', msg);
```

Comment: I tried using the 2nd one but on my terminal it returned  `cannot call method 'emit' of undefine`

Comment: Oh geez, sorry... bad pre-1.0 habits:  io.sockets.emit('chat message', msg);

Comment: Thanks You helped me again.. my question from the other article was kinda off-topic so I posted a new one.. anyway this one is neat